# lappy conditional on variable value

Tags: r, function, lapply

I want to lappy two functions on a data set conditional on the value of a specific variable.

```
first_function <- function(x) {return (x + 0)}
second_function <- function(x) {return (x + 1)}

df <- data.frame(Letters = c("A","B","B"), Numbers = 1:3)
```

Someting like:

```
df <- lapply(df, if(df$Letters=="A") first_function else second_function )
```

To produce:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(Letters = c("A","B","B"), Numbers = c(1,3,4))
```

Comment: You may need `ifelse` i.e. `df$Numbers <- with(df, ifelse(Letters == "A", first_function(Numbers), second_function(Numbers)))`

Comment: Your current application of `lapply` is incorrect. Regardless of which function you use, `lapply` will apply the function on each column of the frame. Since you have non-`numeric` columns, they will produce errors (if `character`) or warnings and `NA`s (if `factor`). Based on a naive interpretation of your functions, I think @akrun's solution is more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `dplyr` and `purrr`. Obviously this is a basic function, but you should be able to build on it for your needs:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
calc <- function(y, x){
  first_function <- function(x) {return (x + 0)}
  second_function <- function(x) {return (x + 1)}

  if(y == "A")
    return(first_function(x))

    return(second_function(x))
}

df <- data.frame(Letters = c("A","B","B"), Numbers = 1:3)

df %>% 
  mutate(Numbers = map2_dbl(Letters, Numbers, ~calc(.x,.y)))

  Letters Numbers
1       A       1
2       B       3
3       B       4

>(df_desired <- data.frame(Letters = c("A","B","B"), Numbers = c(1,3,4)))
      Letters Numbers
1       A       1
2       B       3
3       B       4
```

**BENCHMARKING**

I am not a data.table expert (feel free to add), so did not incorporate here. But, @R Yoda is correct. Although it reads nicely and future you will find it easier to read and extend the function, the `purrr` solution is not that fast. I liked the `ifelse` approach, so added `case_when` which is easier to scale when dealing with multiple functions. Here are a couple solutions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(microbenchmark)

first_function <- function(x) {return (x + 0)}
second_function <- function(x) {return (x + 1)}

calc <- function(y, x){
  if(y == "A")
    return(first_function(x))

    return(second_function(x))
}

df <- data.frame(Letters = rep(c("A","B","B"),1000), Numbers = 1:3)

basic <- function(){
  data.frame(df$Letters, apply(df, 1, function(row) {
    num <- as.numeric(row['Numbers'])
    if (row['Letters'] == 'A') first_function(num) else second_function(num)
  }))
}

dplyr_purrr <- function(){
  df %>% 
    mutate(Numbers = map2_dbl(Letters, Numbers, ~calc(.x,.y)))
}

dplyr_case_when <- function(){
  df %>% 
    mutate(Numbers = case_when(
        Letters == "A" ~ first_function(Numbers),
        TRUE ~ second_function(Numbers)))
}

map_list <- function(){
   data.frame(df$Letters, map2_dbl(df2$Letters, df2$Numbers, ~calc(.x, .y)))
}

within_mapply <- function(){
  within(df, Numbers <- mapply(Letters, Numbers, 
                               FUN = function(x, y){
    switch(x, 
           "A" = first_function(y),
           "B" = second_function(y))
    }))
}

within_ifelse <- function(){

  within(df, Numbers <- ifelse(Letters == "A",
                               first_function(Numbers),
                               second_function(Numbers)))
}

within_case_when <- function(){

  within(df, Numbers <- case_when(
    Letters == "A" ~ first_function(Numbers),
    TRUE ~ second_function(Numbers)))
}

(mbm <- microbenchmark(
  basic(),
  dplyr_purrr(),
  dplyr_case_when(),
  map_list(),
  within_mapply(),
  within_ifelse(),
  within_case_when(),
  times = 1000
))

Unit: microseconds
               expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval    cld
            basic() 12816.427 24028.3375 27719.8182 26741.7770 29417.267 277756.650  1000      f
      dplyr_purrr()  9682.884 17817.0475 20072.2752 19736.8445 21767.001  48344.265  1000     e 
  dplyr_case_when()  1098.258  2096.2080  2426.7183  2325.7470  2625.439   9039.601  1000  b    
         map_list()  8764.319 16873.8670 18962.8540 18586.2790 20599.000  41524.564  1000    d  
    within_mapply()  6718.368 12397.1440 13806.1752 13671.8120 14942.583  24958.390  1000   c   
    within_ifelse()   279.796   586.6675   690.1919   653.3345   737.232   8131.292  1000 a     
 within_case_when()   470.155   955.8990  1170.4641  1070.5655  1219.284  46736.879  1000 a
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant solution to encapsulate the conditional logic in a function but this seems to impact the performance since the function is called per row (but performance was no requirement in the question)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this with `*apply` would be to put the whole logic (with the conditional and the two functions) into another function and use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to pass the data in row by row (`lapply` will pass in the data by column):

```
apply(df, 1, function(row) {
    num <- as.numeric(row['Numbers'])
    if (row['Letters'] == 'A') first_function(num) else second_function(num)
    })

[1] 1 3 4
```

The problem with this approach, at @r2evans points out in the comment below, is that when you use `apply` with a heterogeneous data.frame (in this case, `Letters` is type `factor` while `Numbers` is type `integer`) each row passed into the applied function is passed as a vector which can only have a single type, so everything in the row is coerced to the same type (in this case `character`). This is why it's necessary to use `as.numeric(row['Numbers'])`, to turn `Numbers` back into type `numeric`. Depending on your data, this could be a simple fix (as above) or it could make things much more complicated and bug-prone. Either way @akrun's solution is much better, since it preserves each variable's original data type.

Comment: The fact that you have to force `as.numeric(row['Numbers'])` indicates the cost/consequence of using `apply` across all columns of a heterogeneous frame. Larger data and/or other classes of data will have different costs/consequences.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` has difficulty in this case because it's column-based. However you can try transpose your data by `t()` and use `lapply` if you persist. Here I provide two ways which use `mapply` and `ifelse` :

```
df$Letters <- as.character(df$Letters)

# Method 1
within(df, Numbers <- mapply(Letters, Numbers, FUN = function(x, y){
                             switch(x, "A" = first_function(y),
                                       "B" = second_function(y))
}))

# Method 2
within(df, Numbers <- ifelse(Letters == "A",
                             first_function(Numbers),
                             second_function(Numbers)))
```

Both above got the same outputs :

```
#   Letters Numbers
# 1       A       1
# 2       B       3
# 3       B       4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a `data.table` variant for better performance in case of many data rows (but also showing an implicit conversion problem):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)  # fast convertion from data.frame to data.table

df[  Letters == "A",  Numbers := first_function(Numbers) ]
df[!(Letters == "A"), Numbers := second_function(Numbers)]  # issues a warning, see below

df
# Letters Numbers
# 1:       A       1
# 2:       B       3
# 3:       B       4
```

The issued warning is:

> Warning message: In `[.data.table`(df, !(Letters == "A"),
>   `:=`(Numbers, second_function(Numbers))) :   Coerced 'double' RHS to
>   'integer' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision.
>   Either change the target column ['Numbers'] to 'double' first (by
>   creating a new 'double' vector length 3 (nrows of entire table) and
>   assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'integer' (e.g.
>   1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for
>   speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the
>   table and stick to it, please.

The reason is that the data.frame column `Numbers` is an integer

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Letters: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2 2
 $ Numbers: int  1 2 3
```

but the functions return a double (for whatever reason):

```
> typeof(first_function(df$Numbers))
[1] "double"
```